# Reading File From Network Location

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, network-share

I am having Bunch of Files in A folder which is shared on Network Drive . I am trying to Access those Files into my Code . But It is giving an error:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException was unhandled by user code

```
Fname = txtwbs.Text;
DirectoryInfo objDir = new DirectoryInfo("Y:\\");
_xmlpath = objDir + "\\" + Fname + "\\" + Fname + ".xml";
if (File.Exists(_xmlpath ))
{
    reader(_xmlpath);
}
```

I have Also used:

```
file = fopen("\\\\10.0.2.20\\smartjobs\\Eto\\"+Fname);
```

I am Able to Read File from My Local PC But it is giving Exception Only for Network Location .Please let me know how can I read File From Network Shared Location .

And Also How Can I Make A tree view of Folders into Asp.net Web Application .

Directory Structure is Like that

```
\\10.0.2.20\Smartjobs\Eto\
```

this is Parent Directory It is congaing Nos of Folder having XML Documents.

Comment: Can you view the files from some other location such as from the explorer window? Maybe your machine does not have read access.

Comment: What identity does your Application Pool run under? That identity most likely has no access to network drives.

Answer (score 1):

In asp.net, you cannot access network folder directly because asp.net runs under anonymous user account, that account does not have access to that location.

You can give rights to "Everyone" in that shared location and see if it is working. However this is not advisable.

Alternativly You may have to do impersonation in asp.net code when accessing network location. You will have to do implersonation with the user who has access to that shared location.

Answer (score 1):

You may have map the shared directory as a user, but you forget that the asp.net is running under the account of the pool, and there you do not have connect the y:\ with the shared directory.

The next think that you can do is to direct try to connect via the network shared name, eg: `\\SharedCom\fulldir\file.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that the ASP.net page run as a certain user with access to the file. Then, you need to enable `impersonation` in your `web.config` file in order for ASP.net to actually access the file as that `user`.

> Your Y drive is a mapped network drive. You need to use the network
>   url eg `\\server\Smartjobs\Eto\xyz.xml`

You specify the `name` of the file on the `network` just like you do from anywhere else:

```
Dim myStream As IO.FileStream = IO.File.Open("\\myserver\myshare\myfile", IO.FileMode.Open)
Dim myBytes As Byte()
myStream.Read(myBytes, 0, numberOfBytesToRead)
```

More reference:
[Unable to List File or Directory Contents on ASP.NET Page using Shared Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922240/unable-to-list-file-or-directory-contents-on-asp-net-page-using-shared-drive)
[Using file on network via IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670761/using-file-on-network-via-iis)