# Cannot find file Exception with FileStream, opens in Explorer

Tags: c#, file-io, filestream

I have the following code:

```
FileStream file = new FileStream(@"\\srv\dscan$\001\unknown\2012-04\0011200001001700_001.pdf", System.IO.FileMode.Open);
```

It always throws a `FileNotFoundException`. The strange thing is that if I paste the exact same path above into Windows Explorer, the file can be found and opened perfectly OK.

What can be causing this? Is there a special way of handling file streams on shared network drives?

Comment: Copy the path in to WinExplorer, press enter, copy the path in the explorer bar and try that.

Comment: When I try to copy it in Explorer and/or Chrome it works and downloads / opens the file.

Comment: Yeah, but does the path change when you press enter on explorer?

Comment: Well, if I put it into the browser it changes to `file://srv/dscan$/001/unknown/2012-04/0011200001001700_001.pdf` but if I put it into Explorer it stays the same.

Answer (score 2):

> What can be causing this?

The account under which is executing the process containing this code doesn't have sufficient permissions to read from this location.

Comment: I tried running the program as administrator with the same results... Why does it work in Explorer / my browser?

Answer (score 1):

What Darin Dimitrov says.

The user account that you are logged in under in Windows seems to have the sufficient permissions or maybe you have entered a username and password before which you marked as 'remember'.

When running your code it probably does under minimal rights (UAC) or maybe you are creating a Windows Service, which runs under a different account all together.

Problem could also be related to the dollar sign, which indicates that you are trying to reach a hidden share. I don't know if that is a problem in itself, but could have impact on your (in)sufficient rights.

Answer (score -1):

C# treats a path differently from a windows explorer. 
And one more thing, if you check those posts:
[Reading File From Network Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684879/reading-file-from-network-location)

you will find that you need some more work on the configurations.

Comment: "C# treats a path differently from a windows explorer" could you be more explicit?